# Carriage Return control character (^M) found in wp-config-sample.php

Tags: wp-config, linux, command-line

On a fresh WordPress install in Linux distributions, `wp-config-sample.php` contains Carriage Return control characters that are not found in any other .php file in the distribution.

Running

```
egrep -l $'\r'\$ *.php
```

in WP's base dir, will return only `wp-config-sample.php`

---

I am not worried about eliminating the control character, nor am I worried that it interferes with install operations (it doesn’t).

I’d just like to find out if there’s a reason why `wp-config-sample.php` is the only file with this anomaly.

---

**WP versions**
Issue [was reported](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/control-character-m-found-in-wp-config-sample-php/) in version 4.6.15. It is still present in the latest version 5.5

**Environments**
This behavior has been seen in

- Debian 10 CLI-only
- Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
- Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
- Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

**WordPress distributions**
Install files have been downloaded either

- as .zip file (e.g. wordpress-5.5.zip) or
- as .tar.gz file (e.g. wordpress-5.5.tar.gz)

**Downloads methods**

- via wget: `wget https://wordpress.org/latest.zip`
- via WP CLI: `wp core download`
- via a Web browser (in GUI environments)

Example screenshot from Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS

[image: Ubuntu 12.04.5 tar.gz version]

---

A [Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=wp-config-sample.php%20Carriage%20Return%20control%20character%20(%5EM)) doesn't provide any explanation. I have found only a [similar question](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/control-character-m-found-in-wp-config-sample-php/) in the WP support forum but the reply given is "don't worry about it" and does not provide an explanation for it.

Comment: Would be good feedback to explain why this has been downvoted.

Comment: I just now downloaded clean copies of the latest WordPress release (5.5) in both .zip and .tar.gz flavours from here—https://wordpress.org/download/—and, upon decompressing them, I don't see `^M` characters in `wp-config-sample.php` or in any of the other PHP files I randomly checked (`index.php`, `wp-includes/class-wp-oembed.php`). How are you downloading WordPress to your Linux environment?

Comment: @PatJ either via wget or via WP CLI. Have you opened `wp-config-sample.php` with vi from a command line?

Comment: Yes, all my command-line editing is done with `vi`. (Well, I suppose it's `vim`, if we're getting technical -- specifically `VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Apr 15 2020 06:40:31)`.)

Comment: @PatJ not sure why you are not experiencing this - I have revamped the question with 3 Linux versions and all the methods used, I still see the issue regardless.

Comment: @PatJ instead of `vi` you can also try `grep -l -d recurse '^M' *.php`. Note that the `^M` is obtained by pressing the `CTRL`+`V` and `CTRL`+`M` sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Wordpress support:

> It’s for formatting on legacy DOS based systems. Some DOS and Windows based editors will not handle the file correctly without those additional `^M` carriage return character. A UNIX based system will work with or without them and that’s why they don’t matter.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline
>
> This is how a portion of that file should edit.
>
> ```
> // ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
> /** The name of the database for WordPress */
> define( 'DB_NAME', 'database_name_here' );
> /** MySQL database username */
> define( 'DB_USER', 'username_here' );
> /** MySQL database password */
> define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here' );
> /** MySQL hostname */
> define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
> ```
>
> Which is readable.
>
> If a new user used the Windows notepad editor then the file would may look like this especially on older versions of Windows.
>
> ```
> // ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** ///** The name of the database for WordPress */define( 'DB_NAME', 'database_name_here' );/** MySQL database username */define( 'DB_USER', 'username_here' );/** MySQL database password */define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here' );/** MySQL hostname */define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
> ```
>
> Which is one line of mess. It would still work as a PHP file because the newline is less important than the `;` in the file. The additional `^M`s will be ignored and for those other editor applications the user will see something they can both parse and edit.

Answer (score 2):

Unix and Unix-like operating systems (like Linux) use different line endings in their text files.

> The format of Windows and Unix text files differs slightly. In Windows, lines end with both the line feed and carriage return ASCII characters, but Unix uses only a line feed. As a consequence, some Windows applications will not show the line breaks in Unix-format files. Likewise, Unix programs may display the carriage returns in Windows text files with Ctrl-m (^M) characters at the end of each line.

—From [Convert between Unix and Windows text files](https://kb.iu.edu/d/acux)

Presumably you've copied a file that was created on Windows to a Linux machine, and so you're seeing the Windows line endings when you edit the file on Linux.

[The solution provided in your wordpress.org support post](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/control-character-m-found-in-wp-config-sample-php/) -- use `dos2unix` -- will clean it up.

I can't say precisely why your question was downvoted, as I'm not the downvoter, but if I had to guess I'd say it was because this is a Windows / Linux question, not a specifically WordPress-related question. (Yes, it's a WordPress file, but it's not really related to WordPress development at all.)

Comment: Thx Pat, I have upvoted your answer because I think it made me realize I probably did not write it clearly enough - respectfully, I don't believe it answers my question. I am aware of what you say about the differences between how a Windows environvment Vs. a Unix/Linux environment handles text files. My question is: why is `wp-config-sample.php` the **only** .php file in the Wordpress displaying this behaviour? Also, I think this _is_ specific to WordPress because there is only this one file which appears to differ from the rest. I hope it makes sense. I will edit my question for clarity now.